# Updating multiple instances of same view controller

Tags: ios

The app uses the same profile view controller for every user and simply adjusts the data source for different user's data. When on a users profile, if the current user follows someone, I am trying to update a UILabel on the current users profile controller to reflect this change.

I initially tried using a notification like this:

```
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(userDataChanged) name:@"USER_DATA_UPDATED" object:nil];
```

But the userDataChanged function was only called on the current instance of the view controller, not the one that was sitting in the navigation stack.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless there's a strong reference to a view controller within some other live object, view controllers can be dealloced any time if not currently visible. Obviously, a dead instance cannot receive notifications and won't call the update method.

If you have not already done so, you might want to load the most recent user data from disk once a view controller loads, fetch it from core data or keep that data in some central storage object for easy access. In the most simple case, it might be sufficient to just call the `userDataChanged` from within `viewDidLoad` or `viewWillAppear`.

Of course, notifications are perfectly fine to make the currently visible view controller aware that the data *has been changed*, but you shouldn't rely on it as the only trigger to load data at all.